# sbt programmatically resolve task scope

Tags: scope, sbt, task

How can I refer to a scoped key programmatically? I.e. what is the programmatic equivalent of e.g. scalafmt::test?

Context: neo-sbt-scalafmt defines a TaskKey scalafmt that formats your sources, but it also defines a scope called test (https://github.com/lucidsoftware/neo-sbt-scalafmt/blob/master/sbt-scalafmt/src/main/scala/com/lucidchart/sbt/scalafmt/ScalafmtCorePlugin.scala#L143) that only checks if the sources are in line with the expected format.

Depending on a SettingKey the TaskKey scalaFmt is invoked before compile. I want to introduce a new SettingKey that invokes scalafmt::test instead. The below compiles, but always runs scalafmt, not scalafmt::test.

```
if (scalafmtOnCompile.value) scalafmt in resolvedScoped.value.scope
else if (scalafmtTestOnCompile.value) (test in scalafmt) in resolvedScoped.value.scope
```

https://github.com/lucidsoftware/neo-sbt-scalafmt/blob/master/sbt-scalafmt/src/main/scala/com/lucidchart/sbt/scalafmt/ScalafmtCorePlugin.scala#L170

I asked this question on the sbt gitter channel and just document it here for the next person.

Answer (score 1):

`test in (resolvedScoped.value.scope in scalafmt.key)`

which basically means: "take the existing scope, but make it in scalafmt task scope, that's the scope of test that I want to use"

Kudos to Dale Wijnand for providing the answer originally on gitter.